# Streaming Json file with multiple objects

Tags: java, json, gson, streaming

I have to parse large text file which contains multiple json objects separated by new  line character. Again json objects are large in volume and has to parsed[based on the Json path specified] and store it in DB.

For Streaming text file i am using apache commons LineIterator to read line by line.

example:

```
        LineIterator it = FileUtils.lineIterator(f, "UTF-8");
        int i = 0;
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            readStream(it.nextLine());
        }
```

For Streaming json object i would prefer to use JsonReader from 
com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.

example:

```
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(line);
        JSONArray json_array = obj.getJSONArray("objectName");

        JsonReader reader2 = new JsonReader(new 
        StringReader(json_array.toString()));
        reader2.beginArray();
        while (reader2.hasNext()) {
            ObjectPOJO orgTree = gson.fromJson(reader2, ObjectPOJO.class);
            .../ Do something with the object           
        }
        reader2.endArray();
        reader2.close();
```

But the concern here is when i read a file line by line the entire line is read into memory and using gson streaming does not make any sense[because the line which is json object is already loaded in memory].

Using file streaming with JsonReader like:

```
JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8"));
```

will not help because size of the line is unknown and each line is a json object.

Can anyone suggest what could be the better way to stream both file and json objects?

Any help here is appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Why is size of line required to be known, as String just gets converted to object

Comment: Size of the line need not to be known. The line itself may be a large json object which has to be streamed. 
its like:    File->line streaming ->json streaming